# multirow in a table

Tags: tables, multirow

I have the follwing table

```
\begin{table}[t]
\center
\footnotesize
\caption{the capt}
\label{thelabel}
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | } \hline
%\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Name}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Value}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Value} \\ \hline
\textbf{-} & \textbf{-} \\ \hline
\textit{CoCo} & 23 \\ \hline
\textit{KiKi} & 49 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

How can I have the cells "Name" and "Value" on two rows by removing the cells containing "-", when I use 1`\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Name}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Value}}` it doesnt work

Comment: The question is not very clear: `\multirow` is intended for having a cell vertically centered with respect to several cells next to it. Are you perhaps asking how to get more vertical space above and below "Name" and "Value"?

Comment: @egreg no, what I want is to merge the cell Name with the cell bellow it, using \multirow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you only want some more vertical space in the header which can be done with a vertical invisible rule:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | } \hline
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Value}\\ 
\textbf{-} & \textbf{-} \\ \hline
\textit{CoCo} & 23 \\ \hline
\textit{KiKi} & 49 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, what I want is to merge the cell Name with the cell bellow it, using `\multirow`, how can I use `\multirow` for my question

Comment: then simply do not use `\hline` at the end

Comment: can you modify your example so that I can see the result ?!

Comment: well ok, remove \hline at the multirow line and adding an empty line "& \\ \hline" works, thanks

Comment: see my edit, but I cannot believe that it is what you want??